# Java loop exit condition

Tags: java, networking, singleton, enumerator

I am writing a network server in java, and I have a tiny problem with it.
Let the code do the talking:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
/**
* Another flavor of the server module.
* According to GOD (also known as Joshua Bloch) this is the proper
* implementation of a singleton (Note: serialization).
* 
* @author estol
*/
public enum EnumSingletonServer implements ServerInterface, Runnable
{
    SERVER;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private boolean Listening         = true;

    @Override
    public void bind() {
        this.bind(DEFAULTPORT);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(int Port) {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Port);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.printf("Cannot bind to port %d\nAdditional information:\n%s\nExiting\n", Port, ioe.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Not that elegant, but does not work with flipping the switch, because
    * the loop (in public void run()) is only running when there is an incoming connection(?).
    * 
    * 
    * FIXME
    */
    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        // this.Listening = !this.Listening; // FIXME
        System.exit(0);

    }
    /**
    * Accepting connections on the port, we are bound to.
    * The main loop of the server is a bit broken. Does not exit,
    * if we flip the value of this.Listening, but exit on the next incoming
    * connection. This is a problem.
    * 
    * FIXME
    */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.printf("Listening on %d\n", this.serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            Thread.currentThread().setName("ServerThread");
            // FIXME
            do {
                new Thread(new ServerWorkerThreads(this.serverSocket.accept(), 3)).start();
            } while (this.Listening);

            this.serverSocket.close();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.printf("Cannot accept on, or close port %d\nAdditional information:\n%s\nExiting\n", this.serverSocket.getLocalPort(), ioe.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as said in the comments, if I negate/flip/change the value of the variable this.Listening, the loop does not stop, but exits on the next connection.

I did not implement the server in an enumerator at first, I did it with a class, which failed to be a singleton after being serialized, but that executed as I expected it to do so. I tried a while (condition) done, and also the do while(condition) loop.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried making listening `volatile` to make sure changes are visible from all the threads?

Comment: The accept() method in serversocket blocks, so the loop is not being executed while waiting for a new connection; it only checks whether to continue or not after receiving a new connection. I'm not quite sure how to get the behavior you want though..

Comment: Solved with volatile. Thanks assylias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shutdown method just close the socket instead of setting the variable:

```
this.serverSocket.close()
```

This will raise a **SocketException** on the accept loop and the loop is going to stop.

Comment: Actually this would work too, but if I want to handle the exception, and quit, I am pretty much back at the starting point. (System.exit(0) vs try { this.serverSocket.close(); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.printf("Exiting Gracefully!\n"); System.exit(0) }) Just a longer way of doing the exactly same thing.

Comment: +1 @estol, if you are running unit tests using this library, you are likely to prefer the test to complete and give and status, and continue running tests.  Just having the process die is not so useful. Note: You are more likely to kill a process in production so shutdown() is likely to be only useful in testing.